# IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings fails to load settings after previously stored two DateTimeOffset objects

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Here is an interesting strange behavior (read: bug). I have the following two methods in my simple test app:

```
    private void Save()
    {
        var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        settings["foo"] = new DateTimeOffset(2012, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, TimeSpan.Zero);
        settings["bar"] = new DateTimeOffset(2011, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, TimeSpan.Zero);
        settings.Save();
    }

    private void Load()
    {
        var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        string foo = settings["foo"].ToString();
        string bar = settings["bar"].ToString();
    }
```

When I run my app, I can call Save and then Load and I get the saved values. However, when I stop the app, start it again and attempt to Load, there is a first-chance `InvalidOperationException` (inside the `ApplicationSettings` property) and then the settings object is empty (my values are lost). The exception says:

> Type 'System.DateTimeOffset' cannot be added to list of known types since another type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.DateTimeOffsetAdapter' with the same data contract name 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System:DateTimeOffset' is already present.

When I use ISETool.exe to see what's been saved to `_ApplicationSettings` file, I can see there are two `DateTimeOffset` type references, which is probably the problem. In other words, `IsolatedStorageSettings.Save()` creates a corrupted file that cannot be loaded later.

If I save a different type to "bar" setting, everything works fine. The problem only happens when I save two or more DateTimeOffset values. As a workaround I could save all DateTimeOffset values manually serialized to strings. I'd like to avoid that though.

Comment: Interesting observation. I guess the question here is "is there a better workaround to this problem?".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would seem that you have indeed discovered a bug with the AppliationSettings object.  If you are intent on storing DateTimeOffset values in the ApplicationSettings, then this approach will work.

Create a class with your settings:

```
    public class MyAppSettings
    {
        public DateTimeOffset Foo { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset Bar { get; set; }
    }
```

Change your methods as follows:

```
    private void Save()
    {
        Collection<MyAppSettings> myAppSettings = new Collection<MyAppSettings>();
        myAppSettings.Add(new MyAppSettings
        {
            Foo = new DateTimeOffset(2012, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, TimeSpan.Zero),
            Bar = new DateTimeOffset(2011, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, TimeSpan.Zero)
        });
        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["MyAppSettings"] = myAppSettings;
    }

    private void Load()
    {
        Collection<MyAppSettings> myAppSettings = (Collection<MyAppSettings>)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["MyAppSettings"];
        string foo = myAppSettings.First().Foo.ToString();
        string bar = myAppSettings.First().Bar.ToString();
    }
```

However, I would read this answer for a technique to store this type of information in your own settings file.
[windows phone 7 IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings complex data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6684416/windows-phone-7-isolatedstoragesettings-applicationsettings-complex-data)

Additionally, you could approach this with even more simplicity and avoid using a Collection by changing your Save and Load methods as follows.

```
    private void Save()
    {
        MyAppSettings myAppSettingsSimple = new MyAppSettings
        {
            Foo = new DateTimeOffset(2012, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, TimeSpan.Zero),
            Bar = new DateTimeOffset(2011, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, TimeSpan.Zero)
        };
        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["MyAppSettingsSimple"] = myAppSettingsSimple;
    }

    private void Load()
    {
        MyAppSettings myAppSettingsSimple = (MyAppSettings)IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["MyAppSettingsSimple"];
        txtFoo.Text = myAppSettingsSimple.Foo.ToString();
        txtBar.Text = myAppSettingsSimple.Bar.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. I think you are suggesting that I should create a class to wrap all settings I need to save and then save an instance to `ApplicationSettings` in one assignment. Your code is a bit unclear though. Was there a reason to save a collection and then use First() to get what you need?

Comment: No particular reason to use a Collection.  It's just not uncommon to eventually need Collections when working with settings info.  I've edited the post to include the same basic approach without a Collection.